# Border on table row with space between rows

Tags: tables, border

I am trying to add a left border to a column in a table (tabular, longtable) but I do not want the lines to connect between cells.  Rather, I want a space between the rows, like this image here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about breaking the block across the page boundary, you can set each element (left and right) inside a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}

\newenvironment{labelitem}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-\tabcolsep} }
    #1
  \end{tabular}%
  {\color{blue!75!white}\vrule width 4pt\relax}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ p{\dimexpr.65\linewidth-\tabcolsep-4pt} @{} }
}{%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{labelitem}{Label 1}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{labelitem}

\begin{labelitem}{Label 2}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{labelitem}

\begin{labelitem}{Label 3}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{labelitem}

\begin{labelitem}{Label 4}
  \lipsum*[1]
\end{labelitem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach using a single `tabularx` environment and and empty `\multicolumn`  between each table row:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mymc}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}|X}
label 1 &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \mymc
label 2 &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \mymc
label 3 &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \mymc
label 4 with longer text & \lipsum[5] \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a low-level TeX instruction `\noalign` with a vertical space between the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}|X}
label 1 &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \noalign{\vskip5mm}
label 2 &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \noalign{\vskip5mm}
label 3 &  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \\ \noalign{\vskip5mm}
label 4 with longer text & \lipsum[5] \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]